# Are there Bessarabia resettler individual numbers lists?

Tags: germany

I know that every individual leaving Besserabia and returning to Germany in 1940 was assigned a number such as: (Resettler #61546 - Gottfried Schneider.)  My wife's family fled Tarutino in 1940.  According to the minutes of meetings between Russians and Germans in Sept/Oct 1940 the 3-day "trek" went from Tarutino to Galati.  From there they went north on the Danube. At some point in the process of "resettling" these Germans, they were assigned and given a tag to wear (Umsiedler) with a number.  Somewhere there are records of those numbers.  Where?